# Samsung Galaxy S3 headphones do not plug in

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3, 2 months old, and I have an issue with headphone.
No, not the ' I can not see the headphones icon ' issue rather the headphones do not plug in fully.

I tried pressing them slightly harder but still the white metal portion slightly remains outside the body. At that point, the headphones do get detected but a even a slight touch can make them undetected.

What seems to be the issue here ?

I tested the headphones on my old Nokia and they are detected fine. I am sensing something has to do with them not going in fully ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried plugging in another pair of headphones on your phone? 
If there's a similar problem with plugging in the jack completely, there might be a problem with the jack (female) on the phone. You might want to get it replaced.

Comment: I used flash light to see down the jack and there is nothing obstructing it. If I press the ear phones down slightly with my finger, I can hear sound. When I release my finger, no sound.

Comment: Did you check it with another pair of earphones? <br>
Sounds like there's a problem with the jack. There might not be anything at the bottom of the jack causing this. But I'd suggest you check with another pair of earphones.

Comment: yes, nobody seems to go in.

Comment: It looks like the jack is somehow narrow. If its under warranty, you can get that fixed for free. <br>